# Trouble with my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to learning `JavaScript`, so please bear with me. I was wondering if someone could help me with an assignment that I have. In the wedding.htm file, I have created a calendar that will pop open when you click in the pick a date box. You can select a date, but it has to be after November. I do not know why it does this. I need to be able to select dates in November also. Once I click the next button, it advances to December, but will not go back to November. Yet if I click previous to go to October, it will go back to November. I need help with that also.

Another issue is that I need to be able to click the close button and the calendar closes, but able to reopen upon clicking in the date box. I have found that I can close the calendar after picking a date or clicking the close button as long as it is the month of December. I get the error message `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined"` that I believe is causing these problems from this code: `dateCells[i].innerHTML = dateObject.getDate();`.

```js
"use strict"; // interpret contents in JavaScript strict mode

var dateObject = new Date();

function displayCalendar(whichMonth) {
  var date;
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek;
  var daysInMonth;
  var dateCells;
  var captionValue;
  var month;
  var year;
  var monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  if (whichMonth === -1) {
    dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() - 1);
  } else if (whichMonth === 1) {
    dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  month = dateObject.getMonth();
  year = dateObject.getFullYear();
  dateObject.setDate(1);
  dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay();
  captionValue = monthArray[month] + " " + year;
  document.querySelector("#cal table caption").innerHTML = captionValue;
  if (month === 0 || month === 2 || month === 4 || month === 6 || month === 7 || month === 9 || month === 11) {
    // Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec 
    daysInMonth = 31;
  } else if (month === 1) { // Feb
    if (year % 4 === 0) { // leap year test
      if (year % 100 === 0) {
        // year ending in 00 not a leap year unless
        // divisible by 400
        if (year % 400 === 0) {
          daysInMonth = 29;
        } else {
          daysInMonth = 28;
        }
      } else {
        daysInMonth = 29;
      }
    } else {
      daysInMonth = 28;
    }
  } else { // Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov
    daysInMonth = 30;
  }
  dateCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
    // clear existing table dates
    dateCells[i].innerHTML = "";
    dateCells[i].className = "";
  }
  for (var i = dayOfWeek; i < daysInMonth + dayOfWeek; i++) {
    // add dates to days cells
    dateCells[i].innerHTML = dateObject.getDate();
    dateCells[i].className = "date";
    if (dateToday < dateObject) {
      dateCells[i].className = "futuredate";
    }
    date = dateObject.getDate() + 1;
    dateObject.setDate(date);
  }
  dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth() - 1);
  // reset month to month shown
  document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
  // display calendar if it’s not already visible
}

function selectDate(event) {
  if (event === undefined) { // get caller element in IE8
    event = window.event;
  }
  var callerElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (callerElement.innerHTML === "") {
    // cell contains no date, so don’t close the calendar
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
  dateObject.setDate(callerElement.innerHTML);
  var fullDateToday = new Date();
  var dateToday = Date.UTC(fullDateToday.getFullYear(),
    fullDateToday.getMonth(), fullDateToday.getDate());
  var selectedDate = Date.UTC(dateObject.getFullYear(),
    dateObject.getMonth(), dateObject.getDate());
  if (selectedDate <= dateToday) {
    document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("WeddingDate").value = dateObject.toLocaleDateString();
  hideCalendar();
}

function hideCalendar() {
  document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "none";
}

function prevMo() {
  displayCalendar(-1);
}

function nextMo() {
  displayCalendar(1);
}


function createEventListeners() {
  var dateField = document.getElementById("WeddingDate");
  if (dateField.addEventListener) {
    dateField.addEventListener("click", displayCalendar, false);
  } else if (dateField.attachEvent) {
    dateField.attachEvent("onclick", displayCalendar);
  }
  var dateCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  if (dateCells[0].addEventListener) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
      dateCells[i].addEventListener("click", selectDate, false);
    }
  } else if (dateCells[0].attachEvent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dateCells.length; i++) {
      dateCells[i].attachEvent("onclick", selectDate);
    }
  }
  var closeButton = document.getElementById("close");
  if (closeButton.addEventListener) {
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", hideCalendar, false);
  } else if (closeButton.attachEvent) {
    closeButton.attachEvent("onclick", hideCalendar);
  }
  var prevLink = document.getElementById("prev");
  var nextLink = document.getElementById("next");
  if (prevLink.addEventListener) {
    prevLink.addEventListener("click", prevMo, false);
    nextLink.addEventListener("click", nextMo, false);
  } else if (prevLink.attachEvent) {
    prevLink.attachEvent("onclick", prevMo);
    nextLink.attachEvent("onclick", nextMo);
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

```html
<title>The Lighthouse - Weddings</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="head"><img src="lhouse.jpg" alt="The Lighthouse" /></div>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="upcomingEvents.htm">upcoming events</a></li>
      <li><a href="weddings.htm">weddings</a></li>
      <li><a href="donations.htm">donations</a></li>
      <li><a href="directions.htm">directions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="mainContent">
    <div id="leftColumn">
      <p>Individuals desiring to schedule a wedding cermony should fill out the form to the left. A reservation is not placed on the calendar (schedule) until there has been approval of the site and payment received. There is Non-Refundable fee of $175.00
      </p>
      <br />
      <p> We will contact you to verify your information and schedule your event.
      </p>
      <br />
      <p> <img src="wedding.png"></img>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="rightColumn">
      <h1>Wedding Application</h1>
      <p><span>*</span> indicates required information</p>

      <form name="donationForm" id="donationForm" action="http://www.thelighthours.org/cgi-bin/donation" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="eMail" id="eMail" value="donations@thelighthouse.org" />

        <fieldset id="contact">
          <legend>Contact Information</legend>

          <label class="blockLabel">
    First Name <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
   </label>
          <label class="blockLabel">
    Last Name <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
   </label>
          <label class="blockLabel">
    Home Phone <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
   </label>
          <label class="blockLabel">
    Cell Phone <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
   </label>
          <label class="blockLabel">
    Street Address <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />
   </label>
          <label class="indentLabel">
    City<span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
   </label>
          <label>
    State<span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" maxlength="2" />
   </label>
          <label>
    Zip<span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" maxlength="10" />
   </label>
          <label class="blockLabel">
    E-Mail <span>*</span>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
   </label>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="dateRequested">
          <legend>Date Requested</legend>

          <label class="blockLabel">Pick A Date<span>*</span>
     <input type="text" id="WeddingDate" />
        <div id="cal">
    <div id="prev">&lt; previous</div>
    <div id="next">next &gt;</div>
    <table>
       <caption></caption>
       <tr>
       <th>Sun</th>
       <th>Mon</th>
       <th>Tue</th>
       <th>Wed</th>
       <th>Thu</th>
       <th>Fri</th>
       <th>Sat</th>
       </tr>
                   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
         <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
         <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
         <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
         <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
         <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>       
    </table>
   <p id="close">close <span>&#9746;</span></p>
  </div>
  </label>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="location">
          <legend>Location</legend>
          <input type="radio" id="thegreen" name="loc" />
          <label for="thegreen" id="greenLabel">The Green</label>
          <input type="radio" id="shipcove" name="loc" />
          <label for="shipcove" id="shipcoveLabel">The Ship Cove Picnic Area</label>
          <input type="radio" id="cliffside" name="loc" />
          <label for="cliffside" id="cliffsideLabel">The Cliffside Area</label>



          <label for="comments" class="blockLabel">Comments</label>
          <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />

      </form>

    </div>

    <address>
   The Lighthouse &bull;
   1000 Shore Road. &bull;
   Cape Elizabeth, ME 04107 &bull;
   (207) 799-2661
  </address>

  </div>
  <script src="weddings.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve]

Comment: See my answer below. You were just missing an extra set of `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an extra row of `<td>` tags to work for months that need it.

When I add in:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

then your code works fine. I also suggest that you call `displayCalendar(0);` at the end of `weddings.js` to initialize your calendar for the current month.

Comment: That did get my program to work for me. Thank you. I do not believe I would have ever found that.